# Implementation of Pointers and Objects

Tags: data-structures

[image]

This is the image of a multiple array representation of a double linked list. The object with key 4 follow the object with key 16 in the original linked list. Here 4 appears in key[2] and 16 appears in key[5]. The concept here is to implement a double linked list using arrays without pointers and objects. Can someone explain how the elements are linked with each other.

Comment: So, each value in the next field of the current next/key/prev pair is the index of the next pair?

Comment: Actually I too didn't understand the concept properly and I'm a bit confused in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one has key `9`, and is stored at index `[7]`. You know this because `L` contains the index of the head of the list (7). And sure enough, you can see it has no "prev" value.

From here the next item in the list is stored at index `[5]`. (That's what it tells us in "next" in the array at index `[7]`. This cell has a key of `16`.

From here we go on to `[2]`, having key `4`, and `[3]` having key `1`. This is the last item in the list, as it has no "next".

If you wanted to go backwards, you could look at the "prev" values as well. It's important to note that "next" and "prev" contain numbers of a completely different type from "key". Next and Prev are  referring to array indexes, and are essentially taking the place of pointers in this implementation. Key contains a numeric value that represents the actual contents of the node at that point in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure will work OK. If you're coding C++, you should just define next and prev. of type size_t. However, I don't see any value.

1. Extra math operation is required to go to the next element. With traditional list linked by pointers, you just access the address stored in the pNext field. With your linked list, calculating the address of the next element requires one multiplication and one addition.
2. If your goal is to optimize memory layout for cache-friendliness - it's already done in some implementations of lists. For example, Microsoft's implementation in ATL does that. Instead of allocating elements with new operator, CAtlList class allocates them in batches, that's why standard STL lists typically work 2 times slower when benchmarked against Microsoft's version.